# C# MySql MySqlConnection leave open entire program

Tags: c#, mysql

So what i'm looking to do is open a MysqlConnection and then never close it for the entire application (until the end).

I have this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OpenCon();
}

public static MySqlConnection OpenCon()
{
    MySqlConnection masterOpenCON = new MySqlConnection(SQLStringClass.masterConString);
    masterOpenCON.Open();
    return masterOpenCON;
}
```

However, i believe this  will continuously open the connect, how do i open the connection once and reference the connection throughout the app.  This is how I am calling it right now.

```
try
{
    MySqlCommand mysqlprocessCmdInsertItem = new MySqlCommand(SQLStringClass.mySQLCOMMAND, OpenCon());
    mysqlprocessCmdInsertItem.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the connection in a `static` field or property.

For example:

```
public static MySqlConnection Connection { get; private set; }

Connection = OpenCon();
```

Comment: is that not what I am doing?  If not do you have an example?

Comment: No, that's not what you're doing.

Comment: In case anybody was wondering do the Connection = OpenCon();
 inside of Man(string[] args)

Answer (score 9):

Don't bother with this. The MySQL ADO.NET Connector [uses a pool of connections](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html) meaning that when you call `.Open` on a connection you are not actually opening it, you are drawing it from the existing connection pool and when you call `.Close` you are not closing it, you are returning it to the connection pool so that it can be reused.

IIRC connection pooling is enabled by default but you could control it with the following parameters on your connection string:

- Pooling = true
- Max Pool Size = 100
- Min Pool Size = 0

So when you want to send a SQL query all you need to do is the following and let the ADO.NET framework worry about connections:

```
using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(SQLStringClass.masterConString))
using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Foo FROM Bar";
    using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I would recommend you avoiding any static members and manual connection handling.

Comment: I don't know what MySql does.

Comment: This is not always the case. I learned the hard way, that e.g. MDB files are _never_ pooled (the provider doesn't support it). Same _can_ be true for other providers, too.

Comment: @SLaks, @Uwe Keim, here's the documentation about MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-programming-connection-pooling.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to also specify the connection object as static.

```
private static MySqlConnection masterOpenCON;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    OpenCon();
}

public static MySqlConnection OpenCon()
{
    masterOpenCON = new MySqlConnection(SQLStringClass.masterConString);
    masterOpenCON.Open();
    return masterOpenCON;
}
```